# How do I grab the error code if sqlite3_prepare_v2() returns one?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, error-handling, sqlite

Largely following [Ray Wenderlich's SQLite tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-101-for-iphone-developers-making-our-app), I'm writing a fairly straightforward app that displays information pulled down from a server. The basic structure of my SQLite queries (to the local database, not the server) is as follows:

```
{
    NSMutableArray *list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *query = @"SELECT _id, type FROM table ORDER BY type"; // As appropriate.
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_db, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            // Process the returned values...
            int rowNumber = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);

            // Initialize the object.
            // Push the object onto the array.
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    } else {
        // Log the error.
    }
    return list;
}
```

My question is, **what's the best way to check for an error if the `if` statement returns false?** The simplest solution to me seems to store the return value of `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` as an `int` and check *that* against `SQLITE_OK`. What about calling `sqlite_errmsg()`?

I did look into `sqlite_exec()` but I haven't had any luck in getting forays to compile and I don't feel confident enough in my understanding of callbacks in C to properly maintain code that uses them. It passes an argument for the error though, which is what got me looking into it in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get an error message, you must indeed call `sqlite3_errmsg`.

`sqlite3_exec` would give you the same string.

Comment: So it sounds as if the `else` block could contain simply `NSLog(@"Database returned error %d: %s", sqlite3_errcode(_db), sqlite3_errmsg(_db));`

Comment: Yes; although the error code isn't very useful if you also have the message (the information in the code is a subset of the information in the message).

Comment: Thanks. Hadn't had the chance to test it yet.

Comment: I have at least one case in a client app where the message is 'not an error' which is not hugely helpful. I suggest you also save and log the result code (wishing the original programmer had done so here).

Comment: @AndyDent This is not possible; the message "not an error" can be returned only if the error code is zero.

Comment: Code that is crashing with string message 'not an error' is:
  if ( (rc=sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [queryString UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL)) != SQLITE_OK) {
  NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));